# Añadir filas con jQuery y Laravel Filemanager

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas utilizo [Laravel filemanger](https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/) en mis proyectos. Es como una interfaz para poder subir archivos al servidor.

Mi problema es que quiero poder ir añadiendo inputs en un formulario según necesite más campos para subir archivos.

Cada input tiene un icono que cuando le pulsas abre una ventana emergente para seleccionar un archivo ya en el servidor o subir uno nuevo, pero cuando añado ya la primera fila no hace nada, ni se abre ventana, ni me arroja error ni nada.

**Mi HTML**

```
<div id="tecnologias" class="espaciosMensaje">
   <div id="mensaje_tecnologias">
     <div class="alert alert-info fontAlert" role="alert">
       Añade un fotolito
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="padBtnFila">
  <div id="AddMoreMedida_tecnologia" class="pull-right">
    <a href="#" id="AddTecnologia" class="btn btn-info pull-right btnSave margenBrn AddTecnologia">Añadir fila</a><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="lineBreak_tecnologias"></div>
```

**Mi JavaScript**

```
window.onload=function() {
        var MaxFilasTecnologias       = 40; //maximum extra input boxes allowed
        var Tecnologias   = $("#tecnologias"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
        var AddTecnologia       = $("#AddTecnologia"); //Add button ID
        
        var d = Tecnologias.length; //initlal text box count
        var contador=1; //to keep track of text box added

        //on add input button click
        //$(AddTecnologia).click(function (e) {
        $(".lasTecnologias").on('click', 'a.AddTecnologia',function(e) {
                //max input box allowed
                if(d <= MaxFilasTecnologias) {
                    contador++; //text box added ncrement
                    
                    if(contador >= 2){
                        $("#mensaje_tecnologias").css({"display": "none"});
                    }
                    console.log(contador)
                    //add input box
                    $(Tecnologias).append('<div class="form-group" style="position:relative;">\
                            <label for="fotolito" class="labelMio" style="position: relative;">Subir fotolito</label>\
                            <span><a data-input="thumbnail50'+ contador +'" data-preview="holder50'+ contador +'" class="fileManager">\
                                <i class="fas fa-plus addArchivo"></i>\
                            </a></span><input id="thumbnail50'+ contador +'" class="form-control myInput" type="text" name="fotolito" style="padding-right: 40px;"></div>\
                        <a href="#" class="remove_tecnologia deleteFila removeFilas"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>\
                    </div>');
                    d++; //text box increment
                    
                    $("#AddMoreMedida_tecnologia").show();
                    
                    $('AddTecnologia').html("Add field");
                    
                    // Delete the "add"-link if there is 3 fields.
                    if(d == 40) {
                        $("#AddMoreMedida_tecnologia").hide();
                            $("#lineBreak_tecnologias").html("<br>");
                    }
                }
                return false;
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista parece que estás intentando asignar el evento 'click' al botón de añadir fila antes de que se haya cargado la página. Para solucionar esto, puedes encapsular todo tu código en una función y luego llamarla al final del documento.

También hay un pequeño error de sintaxis en tu código JavaScript. En la línea que dice **$('AddTecnologia').html("Add field");**, debería ser **$('#AddTecnologia').html("Add field");** en lugar de **$('AddTecnologia')**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var MaxFilasTecnologias = 40; // Máximo de filas permitidas
    var Tecnologias = $("#tecnologias"); // Contenedor de los inputs
    var AddTecnologia = $("#AddTecnologia"); // Botón para añadir inputs
    var d = Tecnologias.children().length; // Contador de inputs
    var contador = d + 1; // Inicialización del contador para nuevos inputs

    // Función para abrir el file manager
    $(document).on('click', '.fileManager', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var input = $(this).data('input');
        window.open('/file-manager/fm-button?input=' + input, 'fm', 'width=1200,height=800');
    });

    // Añadir nuevo input al hacer clic en el botón de añadir
    $(document).on('click', '#AddTecnologia', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Comprobar si se ha alcanzado el máximo de inputs permitidos
        if (d < MaxFilasTecnologias) {
            // Añadir nuevo input
            $(Tecnologias).append('<div class="form-group" style="position:relative;">\
                <label for="fotolito_' + contador + '" class="labelMio" style="position:relative;">Subir fotolito</label>\
                <span><a data-input="thumbnail50_' + contador + '" class="fileManager">\
                    <i class="fas fa-plus addArchivo"></i>\
                </a></span><input id="thumbnail50_' + contador + '" class="form-control myInput" type="text" name="fotolito_' + contador + '" style="padding-right: 40px;"></div>\
                <a href="#" class="remove_tecnologia deleteFila removeFilas"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>');
            d++; // Incrementar contador de inputs
            contador++; // Incrementar contador de nuevos inputs
            $("#AddMoreMedida_tecnologia").show();
            $('#AddTecnologia').html("Añadir fila");
            // Ocultar botón de añadir si se ha alcanzado el máximo de inputs permitidos
            if (d == MaxFilasTecnologias) {
                $("#AddMoreMedida_tecnologia").hide();
                $("#lineBreak_tecnologias").html("<br>");
            }
        }
    });

    // Eliminar input al hacer clic en el botón de eliminar
    $(document).on('click', '.remove_tecnologia', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        d--; // Decrementar contador de inputs
        contador--; // Decrementar contador de nuevos inputs
        // Mostrar botón de añadir si se ha eliminado un input
        if (d < MaxFilasTecnologias) {
            $("#AddMoreMedida_tecnologia").show();
        }
        // Mostrar mensaje si no quedan inputs
        if (d == 0) {
            $("#mensaje_tecnologias").css({"display": "block"});
        }
    });
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema con tu código.

Comment: Hola @xhamu y bienvenido, gracias por tu respuesta pero le sigue sucediendo lo mismo, cuando pulso no hace nada